# Align SpriteText position

Tags: 2d, unity, javascript, unityscript

i have this function which aligns text.

```
static function AlignTxt(obj : GameObject, txtAnchor : SpriteText.Anchor_Pos,
txtAlign : SpriteText.Alignment_Type)
{   
obj.GetComponent(SpriteText).SetAnchor(txtAnchor);
obj.GetComponent(SpriteText).SetAlignment(txtAlign);    
}
```

The above function is called from this function..

```
txtlib.AlignTxt(powerTxt, SpriteText.Anchor_Pos.Middle_Left, SpriteText.Alignment_Type.Center);
```

But i get this error on AlignTxt Function :

The name 'SpriteText.Anchor_Pos' does not denote a valid type ('not found').
The name 'SpriteText.Alignment_Type' does not denote a valid type ('not found').

Can you please help me to solve the error..Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You get those errors because those types (`SpriteText.Anchor_Pos` and `SpriteText.Alignment_Type`)  don't exist.

The correct types are `TextAnchor` and `TextAlignment`.

```
static function AlignTxt(obj : GameObject, txtAnchor : TextAnchor,
  txtAlign : TextAlignment)
  {   
    obj.GetComponent(SpriteText).anchor = TextAnchor.txtAnchor;
    obj.GetComponent(SpriteText).alignment = TextAlignment.txtAlign;    
}
```